# location.href works only debug mode

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="NextText">
<a href="javascript:this.frames['checkinFrame'].checkinFile()" class="button">
    fin
</a>
</div>
```

I want button link code change auto-redirect link code

```
<script language="javascript">
    location.href="javascript:this.frames['checkinFrame'].checkinFile()";
</script>
```

it doesn't works in normal firefox.

but works well in firefox debug line by line.

what's the ploblem?

Comment: Why do you use this `href` this way? Why not simply `this.frames['checkinFrame'].checkinFile()`?

Comment: So you want to execute the function `javascript:this.frames['checkinFrame'].checkinFile()` at the load of the page which otherwise happens only on clicking the link, right?

Comment: try `<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="javascript:this.frames['checkinFrame'].checkinFile()">fin</a>

Comment: <body onload=javascript:this.frames['checkinFrame'].checkinFile();> it's right answer..